# hice un update sqlsrv multiple pero solo actualiza una fila y la otra no - PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-server, php7, sql-server-2008-r2

tengo un formulario donde traigo la información de los familiares de un usuario para luego modificar esa información y actualizarla. Dependiendo de los familiares que tenga este usuario se despliega las tablas con la información de cada familiar.

para traer la información no hay problema, el problema sucede cuando al hacer clic al boton de actualizar solo se modifica la segunda tabla y la primera tabla se queda tal cual sin ningún cambio. En el formulario por medio de esta consulta se imprime el Array del while () que es como traigo los datos y como se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: Por favor añade tambien el codigo del formulario para entender a qué corresponde cada campo. Saludos.

Comment: en un momento lo coloco

Comment: listo ya lo agregue

Comment: Por lo que veo hay partes del formulario que los construyes dentro de un while y le has asignado un name estático por ejemplo a `idF`, entonces al enviar los datos del formulario toma el último valor asignado a ese name, por eso solo actualiza los datos de la 2da persona.

Comment: si exacatmente es eso lo que esta pasando solo me toma el ultimo valor y es eso lo que no he podido solucionar

Comment: Podrías solucionarlo con un acumulador `$i`, le concatenamos a tus name el valor del acumulador, por ejemplo `name="idF.$i."` y al final del while le sumas 1 con `$i++` así tus name serán unicos, eso sí, deberás recibirlos con esos names en `UpdateAlu.php` tanto el `idF0 como el idF1` y los demás que necesites. Saludos.

Comment: entonces a todos los name le concateno $i?, otra cosas debo declarar la variable $i antes por ejemplo: $i = 0; o $i = []; tengo esa duda

Comment: Si, basicamente con eso podrias solucionar tu problema y si efectivamente debes declarar previamente `$i = 0` o `$i = 1` según te convenga solo recuerda recibir los datos con esos mismos names, ya sea  `idF0` e `idF1` o `idF1` e `idF2`, según tu declaración de `$i`.

Comment: sabes como puedo concatenar el caumulador al name ya intente hacer de estas dos maneras name="idF.$i."  que lo toma como nombre y name name="idF<?php .$i. ?>" per me muestra un error de sintaxis  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prueba\vistas\informacion_alu.php on line 337 que es donde esta <input type="hidden" name="idF<?php .$i. ?>" value="<?php echo $id;?>">

Comment: disculpa no habia notado que esa parte estaba solo en HTML, lo que debes hacer es esto `name="idF<?php echo $i;?>"` y recuerda que esto aplica a todos los names, para que todos sean únicos.

Comment: mil gracias, cuando lo tenga listo te lo voy a mostrar para verificar si lo que hice esta bien, en verdad muchas gracias y una disculpa por mi ignorancia estoy aprendiendo php.

Comment: Hola nuevamente mira acabo de editar el codigo del formulario y el de actualización para que veas como quedo, solo que ahora me marca errores para cada variable del UpdateaAlu.php  donde agregue el [$i]

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: idF in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prueba\includes\updateAlu.php on line 70

Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prueba\includes\updateAlu.php on line 70

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prueba\includes\updateAlu.php on line 70

Comment: No, lo de concatenar el acumulador sólo es a la hora de generar el formulario, a la hora de recibir los valores en `updateAlu.php`, lo único que debes hacer es tener un `$_POST['idF1']` y un  `$_POST['idF2']` y así para todos los valores que recibes, luego ejecutar las 2 consultas de update.

Comment: Ya me funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: de nada, ¿ya te funcionó todo correctamente? si es asi voy a poner una respuesta solo para que quede resuelta la duda.

Comment: si me funciono todo caorrectamente, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te mencione en los comentarios, el problema surge ya que el formulario lo construyes dentro de un `while` y le has asignado un `name` estático a los `input`, entonces al enviar los datos del formulario toma el último valor asignado a cada `name` y solo actualiza los datos de la 2da persona, podrías solucionarlo con un acumulador, concatenando a tus `name` el valor del acumulador asi tendrias `name1` y `name2` y en la página `updateAlu.php` recibes ambos valores. Saludos.